# Unwanted white patches on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions

I'm getting unwanted white patches/flashes after the site loads. This problem started only after adding css3 animations to the site.

This is [the page](http://www.privyshoppr.com/get-listed.html) that's experiencing the problem

This is majorly experienced in chrome on a windows computer.

Below is how the animations are triggered.

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#illustrations").css("display", "block");
    $("#illustrations").addClass('anim');
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#illustrations").css("display", "none");

    $("a.transition").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#illustrations").removeClass('anim');
        $("#illustrations").addClass('reverseAnim');

        //window.location = linkLocation;
        redirectInverval();
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        $("#illustrations").css("display", "none");
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }

    function redirectInverval() {
        setInterval(redirectPage, 1000);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.anim {
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 1s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
}
@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        top:-600px;
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
    100% {
        top:0px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst
/* Safari and Chrome */
 {
    0% {
        top:-600px;
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
    100% {
        top:0px;
    }
}
.reverseAnim {
    -webkit-animation:myfirstRev 1s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
@keyframes myfirstRev {
    0% {
        top:0px;
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform:rotate(30deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
    100% {
        top:-600px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirstRev
/* Safari and Chrome */
 {
    0% {
        top:0px;
        /*-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);*/
    }
    50% {
        top: 50px;
        transform:rotate(10deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    100% {
        top:-600px;
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: If i resize the window, it fixes itself.

Comment: Hey yes it does fix it but on reloading or first time loading it appears again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this css:

```
html, body{ height: 100%; }
```

It completely solves your problem. I've just tested it using Tampermonkey so the style is applied on page load instead of applying it using the Developer tools.

On a side note, that background image is huge (463KB). By simply exporting it at 80 jpeg quality instead of 99 you can reduce the size to just 99KB with no noticeable loss of quality. You could also see whether you can achieve the same effect using a smaller background and repeating the background, here's an option: http://halgatewood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/linen_bg_tile.jpg

Comment: hi joe, thank you! this worked for the white patch that appears below. But there are white patches surrounding the checkboxes upon refresh. this stays for a second or two and then disappears. any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: @DaltonPereira - no problem, I'll take a look at that now.

Comment: Hi Joe, Any luck with the checkbox white patches ?